# Java to Android?

Tags: android, html, jsoup

How can i pass this code in Java to Android, it works fine in Eclipse Java Project.

```
public class GetCode {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.sapo.pt/").get();
    Elements divs = doc.select("div");
    for (Element div : divs)
        System.out.println(div.text());
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me with this? I have Internet acess in AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the android applications must extend Activity.

So your code should be

```
public class GetCode extends Activity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.sapo.pt/").get();
    Elements divs = doc.select("div");
    for (Element div : divs)
        //there are many ways to show data. This is one show it as a pop up message
        Toast toast = Toast.maketext(this, div.text(), Toast.Lenght_Short);
        toast.show;
        //this prints it in the logcat
        debug.i("my app", div.text);
        //Alert dialogues work too
    }
}
```

and you can't pass arguments to it. If you want to pass data between activities, use bundles. You must write it within an android project, since it references to layouts and generated code that is created at compile time by eclipse's android plugin.

If div.text() is a html text, you can use

```
 WebView wv = new WebView(this);
 wv.loadData(div.text() , "text/html", "utf-8");
```

and then use it like a view, for example in your Alert Dialog ad, use

```
   ad.setView(wv);
```

Comment: @BrunoTaxi remember to accept the answer if you find it useful. If you have other doubts post it here and i'll expand the answer